# Autowire auto-configured dependency in integration test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection, integration-testing

As part of my Spring Boot app, I have a Thymeleaf HTML template rendering service:

```kotlin
@Service
class TemplateService(private val templateEngine: SpringTemplateEngine) {

    fun renderTemplate(templateName: String, vars: Map<String, Any>): String =
        templateEngine.process(templateName, Context()
}
```

A method in this service calls `templateEngine.process`. I would like to test `renderTemplate` on a concrete template to make sure that the template is rendered properly. Now, `TemplateEngine` needs a resolver to render a template. Inspecting the source code I see that there's a default `StringTemplateResolver` if there's nothing else configured. The resolver just treats the first argument of `process` as a template string (instead of a template name which is what I want). Naturally then, this template resolver is used in my integration test which is set up like this:

```kotlin
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = [SpringTemplateEngine::class])
class TemplateServiceIT @Autowired constructor(
    springTemplateEngine: SpringTemplateEngine,
) {
    private val templateService = TemplateService(springTemplateEngine)
}
```

This code "works" in the way that all the dependencies are correctly set up and I can create my `TemplateService` instance. However, `SpringTemplateEngine` is configured differently in this test than in the context of a real Spring Boot app because there an extra autoconfiguration is applied which sets up `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` which correctly treats `templateName` as a template name and not a template string.

Now to my question. I want to set up my test context in such a way that:

- Spring injects auto-configured `SpringTemplateEngine` (with `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`)
- I don't have to start the whole Spring Boot app with `SpringBootTest`

Comment: Have you tried using Spring Boot Test annotations, such as `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest` which are meant for testing Spring Boot apps

Comment: As I write in the last paragraph I don't want to use @SpringBootTest because that sets up the whole app. I just want to restrict the set of beans created to `classes`. This would work if e.g. the beans were based on my classes but with autoconfiguration, I get only "basic" beans, whereas I want fully configured beans as in the real Spring app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use `@ImportAutoConfiguration`:

```kotlin
@SpringJUnitConfig(TemplateService::class)
// This auto-configures SpringTemplateEngine
@ImportAutoConfiguration(ThymeleafAutoConfiguration::class)
class TemplateServiceIT @Autowired constructor(private val templateService: TemplateService) {

  ...tests
}
```